# Automated Testing Salesforce one app (3rd party)

Tags: unit-test, salesforce1-app, mobile, ios, automation

Hi I currently in the process of investigating doing mobile test automation(iOS) for the salesforce1 app to verify that changes we've made to the desktop version are present in the mobile version and to run regression tests. Is it possible to get access to files such as .ipa and .app from salesforce that have a resigned certificate for 3rd party testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way you can **officially** get access to the Salesforce1 `IPA` and `APK` files. Of course, there are other tricks in which you can recover these files from the device but they wilL NOT obviously be re-signed for 3rd party testing.

Considering your requirement, the best way to do mobile automation testing is to use the Chrome iOS emulation capabilities with the `/one/one.app` emulator, you can then use it with something like Selenium ChromeDriver

Comment: Thanks very much I will try this and let you know the out come. This should be a very simple task as I already have a selenium framework set up for desktop automation.

Comment: Please mark this as the accepted answer for the benefit of others if this worked for you. Thanks!

Comment: I have just say somewhere the /one/one.app will not be supported from now on ,so this solution will no longer be valid .....

Answer (score 0):

updated information related to mobile automation of salesforce1 is not easy to find. Any advice? Android studio? Eclipse obsolete plugin?